# At a good price or for a good price

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have a doubt about whether you should say

> - “I will sell you these goods for a great price” or
> - “ I will sell you these goods at a great price”

When do you use *at* and when do you use *for*?

Comment: Both are fine. .

Comment: Dictionary definitions of price may help you.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "great": do you mean "very high" or "favourable"?